# Using IFieldChecker in ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, .net

I'm having some problems using `IfieldChecker`.

I have this following code, which I'm trying to test permitted/not permitted fields, according to my workspace

```
public IEnumerable<IFieldError> GetFieldErrors()
        {

        IFieldChecker checker = new FieldCheckerClass();
        IEnumFieldError fieldErrors = null;

        checker.ValidateWorkspace = this.WorkspaceHandler.GetCurrentWorkspace;
        checker.Validate(this.Fields,out fieldErrors,out this._ValidatedFields);

        if (fieldErrors == null)
        {
            yield return null;
        }
        else
        {
            fieldErrors.Reset();
            IFieldError fError = fieldErrors.Next();

            while (fError != null)
            {
                // debug only  
                Console.WriteLine(fError.FieldIndex.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(fError.FieldError.ToString());

                yield return fError;
                fError = fieldErrors.Next();
            }
        }

        yield break;
    }
```

Heres the test

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void FieldBuilder_TestGetFieldErrors()
    {
        fBuilder = new FieldBuilder(this.wHandler);

        fBuilder.AddField(name, alias, esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeBlob, length, doublePrecision, doubleScale, false, false, null,
            false, null);

        Assert.AreEqual(2, fBuilder.GetFieldErrors().Count());
    }
```

In my opinion, this should yield 1. The test completes, and it gives me a green light, but it should fail, since I'm testing with a bunch of values (1, 2, etc.);

The workspace I'm creating is one on C:\, therefore, should not allow a Blob field type.

Any ideas why this is working like this?

**EDIT:** I'm working under the premise that after setting the workspace, ArcObjects would take care of validating it and telling me which types of fields are permitted or not.

Example: FileSystemWorkspace - cannot have Blob field types;

Or, does `IFieldChecker` does not work the way I'm thinking?

Comment: What's the output from the Console.WriteLine() calls?

Comment: I don't think we should be using tags for specific interfaces... that would get messy real quick.

Comment: Shouldn't those last couple of parameters to Validate be ref, not out? I'd have to gin up a test here to be sure, but this sort of thing has nailed me before. [IFieldChecker.Validate documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Validate_Method/002500000342000000/ "IFieldChecker::Validate documentation")

Comment: No, the type library importer turns it into "out". Anyway, in C#, you cannot freely interchange out and ref modifiers, using ref when the signature defines a parameter as out wouldn't even compile.

Comment: Neat. So ESRI's documentation is ... off. Righty-ho. Off to the compiler I go, then.

Comment: Herb, ESRIs docs says ref, but Intellisense says out. So I stuck with Intellisense :P

Comment: Yep. And as @petr_k mentions, the compiler won't allow it. And it was a red herring anyway - the real issue is what Validate claims it might do vs. what it really does....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short version is that the types are (apparently) not checked. I can get Validate to fail for a shapefile if I give it a long field name, or names with invalid characters, but not by giving a bad data type. The documentation does imply that it's only checking names as it states:

"The error codes are stored as a esriFieldNameErrorType." See [esriFieldNameErrorType](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/esriFieldNameErrorType_Constants/00250000004q000000/).

What's interesting is that when I feed it a esriFieldTypeBlob and call Validate, the field type gets changed to esriFieldTypeInteger, even though no error is thrown.

It's kind of implied by the other [out] parameter - "fixedFields". It's thoughtfully fixed your incorrect field definitions for you.